# What Banach spaces of measures are duals of function Banach spaces?

Tags: measure-theory, dual-spaces

[rca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_space#Dual_of_B(%CE%A3))$(X)=$[$C_0(X)$](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Function_vanishing_at_infinity)$^*$ if $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff.

**What other Banach spaces of measures are duals of function Banach spaces?**

Such as [ca$(X)$ or ba$(X)$ or rca$(X)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_space#Dual_of_B(%CE%A3)) under more general (or incomparable) assumptions. With the total variation norm.

Preferably the function space would be **separable and include $1$** (i.e., the constants). Preferably provide a reference (and the assumptions on $X$).

The above [rca result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem#The_representation_theorem_for_the_continuous_dual_of_C0(X)) is about countably-additive measures (Rudin:RCA, 6.19), but also results on finitely-additive measures are welcome (to a lesser extent also the vector-valued ones).

[Note: $C_0(X)$ is separable but does not include $1$ unless $X$ is compact. $Y = C_0(X)+\mathbb K$ with the sup-norm satisfies both criteria but requires us to add one finitely-additive measure to the basis of the measure space to make it the dual space. So does any other extension to $C_0(X)$ too, by the Hahn-Banach theorem. So we should, rather, replace $C_0(X)$ by something else if we want to keep both spaces canonical ones, such as rca$(X)$. Are there such results? $C(X)$ tends to be non-separable.]

ba$(X)$ [is the dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_space#Dual_of_B(%CE%A3)) of the set $B(X)$ of bounded measurable functions on an algebra $\Sigma$ on a set $X$. $B$ contains $1$ (but is not separable unless $\Sigma$ is finite?). Similarly, $L^\infty(\mu)^*$ [consists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_space#Dual_of_L%E2%88%9E(%CE%BC)) of $\mu$-a.c. elements of ba$(X)$, but also $L^\infty$ tends to be nonseparable. Does either have a nice (somehow standard or "canonical") subspace that is the dual of a separable normed space?

Above the scalar field $\mathbb K$ may be $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. I'm interested in $\mathbb R$ but other readers may appreciate $\mathbb C$ results too.

Comment: I don't understand your question ... but in the way you ask, there are a lot of spaces of measures which are dual of function spaces ... all the Lebesgue spaces for example ($(L^p)^*(X) = L^{p'}(X)$ is a subset of the set of bounded measures on $X$).

Comment: Sorry, I now added "Such as ca$(X)$ or ba$(X)$ or rca$(X)$ under more general (or incomparable) assumptions." and "under the total variation norm". Another example is, of course, the set of discrete measures, as it is equivalent to $\ell^1(X)$ (if singletons are measurabe), which is the dual of $c_0(X)$.

Comment: So your question is a little vague. Measure spaces $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$  in general are not vector spaces. $\Omega$ need to be a vector space). Important vector spaces are induced by a measure spaces, e.g. $L_p(\mu)$ $0\leq p\leq \infty$, (which are Banach for $p\geq1)$, their duals, and many others. Also, a measurable space, $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$ induces an important vector space, namely the vector space of complex measure on $(\Omega,\mathscr{B})$ which is Banach, and its dual.

Comment: The book "Hitchhikers guide to Infinite dimensional Analysis" by the late Aliprantis has a table summarizing many interesting spaces and their duals, chapter 14. All that falls into the name of Riesz representation theorems.

Comment: There are a lot of results about this in Dunford and Schwartz, as I recall.  But you're using their notation so maybe you already know about this?

Comment: Thank you all. Aliprantis chapter 14 is really helpful and table 14.1, page 499 lists many such dual spaces. Unfortunately, the primal spaces tend to be nonseparable (or lack 1), and I guess that no separable primal spaces exist unless we find some nice subspaces of measures - which ones? I'll spend more time on A&B and try to get D&S in my hands, too. Oliver, you are right: "spaces of measures" is what I meant, not "measure spaces" (which are [sigma-]algebras). I corrected that too.